# Cant join table at end of query, only in a certain section

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the difference between the two, and why am I able to join the table using the first piece of code? The second version says there is a sql syntax error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT albums.id, albumPublishes.album_title AS title, albumPublishes.album_uuid AS guid, albumPublishes.album_description AS description,publishSchemas.created_at AS createdAt, publishSchemas.updated_at AS updatedAt, publishSchemas.id AS publishId,publishSchemas.note_publish_uuid AS notePublishUUID 
FROM production.publish_schemas AS publishSchemas 
LEFT JOIN production.album_publishes AS albumPublishes ON albumPublishes.visibility = 'Public' AND publishSchemas.album_publish_uuid = albumPublishes.album_publish_uuid 

INNER JOIN production.album_users

LEFT JOIN production.albums AS albums ON albums.album_id = albumPublishes.album_uuid 
WHERE albums.deleted_at IS NULL AND albumPublishes.album_title IS NOT NULL 
AND publishSchemas.publish_environment = 'Staging' HAVING guid != '**' AND guid != '***'
```

This is the version that flags an error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT albums.id, albumPublishes.album_title AS title, albumPublishes.album_uuid AS guid, albumPublishes.album_description AS description,publishSchemas.created_at AS createdAt, publishSchemas.updated_at AS updatedAt, publishSchemas.id AS publishId,publishSchemas.note_publish_uuid AS notePublishUUID 
FROM production.publish_schemas AS publishSchemas 
LEFT JOIN production.album_publishes AS albumPublishes ON albumPublishes.visibility = 'Public' AND publishSchemas.album_publish_uuid = albumPublishes.album_publish_uuid 


LEFT JOIN production.albums AS albums ON albums.album_id = albumPublishes.album_uuid 
WHERE albums.deleted_at IS NULL AND albumPublishes.album_title IS NOT NULL 
AND publishSchemas.publish_environment = 'Staging' HAVING guid != '**' AND guid != '***'

INNER JOIN production.album_users
```

EDIT -- This is the query I wanted to do, but I dont' think I can inject a reference to something that has not been defined yet:

```
SELECT DISTINCT albums.id, albumPublishes.album_title AS title, albumPublishes.album_uuid AS guid, albumPublishes.album_description AS description,publishSchemas.created_at AS createdAt, publishSchemas.updated_at AS updatedAt, publishSchemas.id AS publishId,publishSchemas.note_publish_uuid AS notePublishUUID 
    FROM production.publish_schemas AS publishSchemas 
    LEFT JOIN production.album_publishes AS albumPublishes ON albumPublishes.visibility = 'Public' AND publishSchemas.album_publish_uuid = albumPublishes.album_publish_uuid 

    LEFT JOIN production.album_users as albumUsers on albumUsers.album_id = albums.album_id

    LEFT JOIN production.albums AS albums ON albums.album_id = albumPublishes.album_uuid 
    WHERE albums.deleted_at IS NULL AND albumPublishes.album_title IS NOT NULL 
    AND publishSchemas.publish_environment = 'Staging' HAVING guid != '**' AND guid != '***'
```

Comment: Why? Because the second one is invalid MySQL syntax. What exactly is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I need to join a table to do more filters. I don't understand why doing a join has to be in a certain order if all you're doing is 'mashing' these tables together?

Comment: INNER JOIN after a having clause?  DBENGINES REQUIRE syntax to be in specific order.  you either need ()'s around somethings, or you're missing order of operations: SELECT, FROM (JOINS), WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY

Comment: As Patrick indicated, the syntax is incorrect. Specifically, joins need to precede the where clause (unless they're part of a subquery)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you _want_ to be able to do it the second way instead of the first?

Comment: yes, I just commented to barmar's comment. I hope that makes sense.. I'll clarify if it's unclear.

Comment: Simply join on `production.albums` before you join on `production.album_users`. Similar to [Sagar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24002397/1505169), but just add your `ON` clause to the `production.album_users` join.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is very strict about the order of clauses in a query. It must be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN ... JOIN ... JOIN ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT ...
```

(I've omitted some uncommon clauses.) Most of the clauses are optional, but when they're used they must be in the appropriate place in this ordering.

The query you're trying to do should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT albums.id, albumPublishes.album_title AS title, albumPublishes.album_uuid AS guid, albumPublishes.album_description AS description,publishSchemas.created_at AS createdAt, publishSchemas.updated_at AS updatedAt, publishSchemas.id AS publishId,publishSchemas.note_publish_uuid AS notePublishUUID 
FROM production.publish_schemas AS publishSchemas 
LEFT JOIN production.album_publishes AS albumPublishes ON albumPublishes.visibility = 'Public' AND publishSchemas.album_publish_uuid = albumPublishes.album_publish_uuid 
LEFT JOIN production.albums AS albums ON albums.album_id = albumPublishes.album_uuid 
LEFT JOIN production.album_users as albumUsers on albumUsers.album_id = albums.album_id
WHERE albums.deleted_at IS NULL AND albumPublishes.album_title IS NOT NULL 
AND publishSchemas.publish_environment = 'Staging' HAVING guid != '**' AND guid != '***'
```

You just need to order all the joins so that their `ON` clauses only reference tables from previous `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses. I swapped the order of the last two `LEFT JOIN` clauses.

Comment: I wanted to try and inject this statement inside the center - left join production.album_users as albumUsers on albumUsers.album_id = albums.album_id       The problem is I think that albums.album_id is not defined at this point. What is the workaround?

Comment: Put it anywhere after `LEFT JOIN product.albums`, then `albums.album_id` will be defined.

Comment: Sweet - I'm starting to get this to work. I thought you couldn't do that, because I had a where clause that was attached to the join statement, but I understand the join a little more. I like to think of it as attaching everything before

Comment: `ON` clauses apply to just that join, `WHERE` clauses apply to the whole joined row.

Comment: I would not describe `join` as a clause (nor `on`).  These a subclauses of `from`.  The documentation for `select` pretty much shows the different clauses, although it is not explicit about the terminology.  Your list is otherwise quite good for commonly used SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure that the distinction between clause and subclause is important in this context. It affects optional dependencies (you can't have `JOIN` or `WHERE` outside `FROM`), but not the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Joins must before clause, check this one code

```
    SELECT DISTINCT albums.id, albumPublishes.album_title AS title, albumPublishes.album_uuid AS guid, albumPublishes.album_description AS description,publishSchemas.created_at AS createdAt, publishSchemas.updated_at AS updatedAt, publishSchemas.id AS publishId,publishSchemas.note_publish_uuid AS notePublishUUID 
    FROM production.publish_schemas AS publishSchemas 

     LEFT JOIN production.album_publishes AS albumPublishes ON albumPublishes.visibility = 'Public' AND publishSchemas.album_publish_uuid = albumPublishes.album_publish_uuid 

    LEFT JOIN production.albums AS albums ON albums.album_id = albumPublishes.album_uuid 

    INNER JOIN production.album_users

    WHERE albums.deleted_at IS NULL AND albumPublishes.album_title IS NOT NULL 
    AND publishSchemas.publish_environment = 'Staging' HAVING guid != '**' AND guid != '***'
```